# How to use one httpd.conf for testing and production server?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

On my testing server I want to listen to:
127.0.0.1

and on my productaion server I want to listen to:

#### .###.###.

I am searching for something like that:

```
<if #server=>
Listen 127.0.0.1
</if #server=>
```

There is something like that in apache?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `-DTEST` to the httpd command line and then use

```
<IfDefine TEST>
</IfDefine>
```

and

```
<IfDefine !TEST>
</IfDefine>
```

to enable different sections of the config file.

Comment: Can I do it without command line? like reading from the system environment?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but if you use a script to start httpd you could do the test there, e.g `httpd -D${MYENVVAR:-PRODUCTION}`

Comment: Thank you very much, I added other question about the same topic: 
http://serverfault.com/questions/477970/can-i-add-argument-to-httpd-when-i-am-using-xampp

Answer (score 1):

VirtualHost might be what you are needing

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
..... Directives.....
</VirtualHost>
```

Or IP based VirtualHost on each server.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
..... Directives.....
</VirtualHost>
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Could you just run two separate apache instances listening on separate ports.  There would be less of a chance of the testing environment causing problems for your production server.  Also restarts would not affect your production environment

Comment: No, this is two differences server. (My office, and Web farm). I want to be able to just copy the httpd.conf every time I change something.